# Operator() crashing program on MSVC C++17 (2019)

Tags: c++, set, comparator

The following code doesn't work with MSVC++ 2019, but it works on GCC compiler.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct MyData {

    MyData() {}
    MyData(std::string keyA, std::string keyB) :keyA(keyA), keyB(keyB) {}

    std::string keyA;
    std::string keyB;
};


struct Compare {

    bool operator() (const MyData& lhs, const MyData& rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs.keyA < rhs.keyA)
            return true;

        if (lhs.keyB < rhs.keyB)
            return true;

        else
            // All else conditions would be false
            return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<MyData, Compare> s;

    s.insert(MyData("Clark", "Alice"));
    s.insert(MyData("Bob", "Alice"));
    s.insert(MyData("Alice", "Bob"));
    s.insert(MyData("Derek", "Clark"));

    for (auto& i : s)
    {
        std::cout << i.keyA << ", " << i.keyB << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here's the error on MSVC:

[image]

While on GCC, it shows this output:

```
Alice, Bob
Bob, Alice
Clark, Alice
Derek, Clark

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.971 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What's causing this error, and how to define the operator correctly?

Comment: What should happen if `lhs.keyA == "Bob"` and `rhs.keyA == "Alice"`?

Comment: Note that you can perform a lexicographic comparison quite compactly using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: Note: If you haven't noticed already, *Press retry to debug the application* is some of the best advice ever given to programmers.

Comment: The visual studio does add some checks into executables produced for the debug configutation. In this case I guess the issue is your comparator not being antisymetric.

Comment: Thanks, I tried 'retry'. it gives me no output.

Comment: Output's not what you're looking for. You want to see what values caused the failure. One you know those, you'll have a pretty good idea of where to put breakpoints in order to stop the program before it fails and then step through the problem area to watch what leads up to the failure.

Comment: @user963241 -- Also, what you are seeing is *not* a crash.  It is an assert() that is occurring.  There is a big difference between a crash and an assertion.  The program has not technically just stopped working (a crash).  The program made a check using `assert()`, and the asserted condition wasn't satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator fails to adhere to the rules for [strict weak ordering](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), that is to say it is possible to have the following situation:

```
a < b
b < c
a >= c
```

MSVC has evidently detected this and raised an assertion failure.

To fix this, you can change your comparator as follows:

```
bool operator() (const MyData& lhs, const MyData& rhs) const
{
    if (lhs.keyA < rhs.keyA)
        return true;

    if (lhs.keyA == rhs.keyA && lhs.keyB < rhs.keyB)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Or, more compactly, use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
bool operator() (const MyData& lhs, const MyData& rhs) const
{
    return std::tie (lhs.keyA, lhs.keyB) < std::tie (rhs.keyA, rhs.keyB);
}
```

I also got rid of the redundant `else`.

Comment: If this code works on GCC, does it mean I have this "strict weak ordering" thing correctly defined for GCC?

Comment: No it doesn't, it's just that `gcc` doesn't check for that.

Comment: Not providing a comparator that guarantees Strict Weak Ordering results in Undefined behaviour, and one of the really cool things about the behaviour being undefined is an implementer can insert checks. Microsoft's debug libraries contain a lot of checking that's not explicitly required by the C++ Standard. It is almost always extremely helpful. If you had compiled a Release build you could have found your code "worked" because all those extra checks take time and the Release build uses different libraries that are faster partly because they don't make those extra checks.

Comment: Trying to understand what this strict weak ordering means, so can I define it like [this](https://bpa.st/FPHA) and for 3 keys [this](https://bpa.st/I4UQ)?

Comment: Yes, that works, although you have some redundant tests at the end there.

Comment: The best way to test if a function meets the requirement is with a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). (Note The preceding is opinion) Once you have a working truth table  you can often start simplifying the logic by applying conventional Boolean Algebra rules, assuming you can't see and exploit patterns in the table.

Comment: @user963241 -- The way Visual C++ checks is that in the debug mode, it calls your comparison function twice.  Once with item A and B in that order, and stores the return value you give it.  Then it calls your comparison function again, but this time item B and item A in that order, and checks the return value.  If both return values cannot happen (for example, A >B and at the same time B > A), then that is a violation of the strict weak order, and the debug assertion kicks in.

Comment: How can I check this strict weak ordering with truth table or any other way of logic?

Comment: You can use PaulMcKenzie's test.  That's pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, so I looked at it closely again, and as I understand 'ordering' means that we should compare the `keyA`s first check if they are `lhs.keyA < rhs.keyA` and if `lhs.keyA == rhs.keyA` then it means now we need to sort based on `lhs.keyB < rhs.keyB`. So, basically after keyA is throughly checked for every comparsion, only then we move to `keyB` comparisons and return true when lhs is less than rhs. Is this basically the logic here?

Comment: That's the most straightforward way to do it I find, yes, although it can be done more compactly as R Sahu's answer shows.

Comment: In future, I might have three keys, so hopefully its all a matter of adding them into `std::tie` in the right order i.e. `std::tie(lhs.keyA, lhs.keyB, lhs.keyC) < std::tie(rhs.keyA, rhs.keyB, rhs.keyC);` .

Comment: Yes, that will work as long as the keys themselves compare correctly.  `std::tie` actually returns a [`tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), which in turn has a suitable `operator<` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

`Compare::operator()` is not correct. It does not meet the criteria of [strict weak ordering](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

You can change it to:

```
bool operator() (const MyData& lhs, const MyData& rhs) const
{
    if (lhs.keyA != rhs.keyA)
        return (lhs.keyA < rhs.keyA)
        
    return (lhs.keyB < rhs.keyB);
}
```

It can be further simplified using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

```
bool operator() (const MyData& lhs, const MyData& rhs) const
{
    return std::tie(lhs.keyA, lhs.keyB) < std::tie(rhs.keyA, rhs.keyB);
}
```